# float in C: Size of the exponent

Tags: floating-point, c

This question is very related to the question [Number of decimal of float and double in C](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J4BUz.png). In the second table we may see that the exponent of the float are from -38 to +38. But the IEEE754 standard defines the floats as

```
| sign bit | exponent bits | mantissa | 
| 1 bit    |    8 bits     |  23 bits |
```

Then, the exponent of a float could be 2^6+...2^1+2^0=2^(27)  (from 2^6 because the sign of the exponent). But you can see in the table that the exponent of the floats is from -38 to 38 (range of 38+38+1=78 plus the sign).

What I understand is that the exponent can be larger (with a range of 127, for example from -63 to 63) but C decided to have exponents just from -38 to 38.

**Am I right?**

A very related question is: Why the mantissa starts from -1.2 to 3.4 and it is no from -1.2 to 1.2 or some "balanced"? Is it just a decision?

[image]

Answer (score 5):

$1.2\times 10^{-38}$ is a decimal value. You need to convert it to binary exponential notation to see how the bits are set.

Another small mistake: $2^6+...2^1+2^0$ does not equal $2^{27}$, it equals $2^7-1$.

Answer (score 3):

With 7 exponent bits and one sign bit for the exponent (a total of 8 bits), you can express numbers in the range of $2^{-127}\approx 5.9\cdot 10^{-39}$ to $2^{+127} \approx 1.7\cdot 10^{38}$.

But then you multiply these numbers by numbers of the form $1.bbbbbbb...$ in binary notation, where each of the $b$ stands for one of the 23 bits of the mantissa (i.e., each $b$ is either zero or one). This already gives you a nonsymmetric distribution.

But then not all bit combinations are valid anyway. For example, if I recall correctly, an exponent of -127 is not valid and is interpreted as marking the floating point number as some infinity or NaN, and so in reality, the numbers you can then represent are all of the form
$$
  1.bbbbbbb... \cdot 2^{-126}
\quad\text{to}\quad
  1.bbbbbbb... \cdot 2^{+127}.
$$

Comment: IEEE754 standard uses two's complement to determine the sign, e.g. there is a bias of -128 and any exponent $(e_1e_2e_3e_4e_5e_6e_7e_8)_2$ should be actually read as $(e_1e_2e_3e_4e_5e_6e_7e_8)_2-128$. Because of this, the actual range of exponents is $-128$ to $127$.

Comment: @AbdullahAliSivas Thanks for the correction. I should have just looked this up!

Comment: @AbdullahAliSivas The exponent bias in the IEEE-754 `binary32` (single precision) format is 127, **not** 128. A stored exponent of $0$ is used for zeros and subnormals, a stored exponent of $255$ is used for infinities and NaNs. The stored exponent values of normalized `binary32` operands are thus in $[1, 254]$, corresponding to true exponent values in $[-126, 127]$.